# Is Amazon planning an alternative to the Kindle DX?

Tags: kindle, ebook-readers, e-ink

Over the past four years, I have loved my Kindle DX because of its large screen, which has been very helpful for reading PDFs. The keyboard has also been helpful. It's e-ink, which is easy on the eyes. And let's not forget the occasional Wikipedia access in the middle of nowhere thanks to the free wireless.

I am starting to worry that the DX may fail one of these days, and I wonder what I would replace it with. Amazon still sells it, but there were rumors a couple of years ago that they were dropping it. And the DX has always been slow at turning pages, so if Amazon is not far from releasing an upgrade, it would make no sense to buy a new DX, even if the price is half what it was when it launched.

I have no interest whatsoever in a tablet or any kind of display apart from e-ink. Does anyone have a sense of what Amazon's next move might be for large-screen e-ink readers?

I am not married to mobi, so another large e-ink reader would be acceptable. That being said, I would really like some kind of keyboard input as on the DX, and I realize it is a rare feature.

Comment: Actually the DX was dropped from Amazon's web site, and then [brought back](http://www.theverge.com/2013/6/5/4399144/amazon-brings-back-long-dormant-kindle-dx), at $199 (I believe mine originally cost $379 or thereabouts).  I would love to see a "paperwhite" version of the Kindle DX released.  Meanwhile I am continuing to use my DX for the unique features you mentioned and more (like the accelerometer to flip orientation).

Comment: @tcrosley Yes, it's a fine machine. Sounds like we're on the same boat.

Comment: Are you more interested in physical keyboard or big screen? there are alternatives to DX for each of these categories

Comment: @Woeistg The must-have is the big screen, the physical keyboard is nice to have but not necessary since touch screens seem to be prevalent now.

Comment: Take a look at sony e-reader. It cost 1000$ last year and 800$ this year. It is a nice option if you can afford the price : http://www.sony.com/electronics/digital-paper-notepad

Comment: Who knows? Maybe someday Amazon would have another big-screen device. You'll have to make do with iPads for a while.